# Makefile while loop

Tags: templates, bash, makefile, while-loop

Even after setting SHELL to bash instead of sh, the following does not work:

```
doc:
    while read line; do \
      eval echo "$$line" > $(DOC) \
    done < $(DOC).templ

/bin/bash: -c: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

What I'm trying to do is have a template file with bash parameter comprehensions and such (`$()`, `${}`) and "build" it at compile time. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon before done:

```
doc:
    while read line; do \
      eval echo "$$line" > $(DOC); \
    done < $(DOC).templ
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! Although now the output file is empty. Edit: nevermind, had to use >> to append rather than >. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This answer might come to late ;-), but I think another problem is that your output redirection is in the wrong position:

```
doc:
    while read line; do \
      eval echo "$$line"; \
    done < $(DOC).templ > $(DOC)
```